# Mnemonics to remember various properties of materials

Tags: mnemonic, material-science

I'm trying to figure out how to remember that

- hardness: how resistant it is to deformation
- toughness: how resistant it is to brittle failures
- stress: force on a surface area
- strength: ability to withstand stress without failure
- strain: measurement of deformation of a material

Does anyone know of a mnemonic or easy way? I only know these from googling them, and I'm finding it tricky to remember them.

Comment: Note that this is really language dependent, without your definitions I would not be able to translate and understand them, even tough I know the differences (in French) :p

Comment: Yes I suppose, I'm looking for English definitions. I speak a tiny bit of German, but not enough to understand or translate these definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always used to confuse stress and strain: most of my mnemonics involved making words out of initial letters.

> **When you're stressed, you show the strain.**

Stress is what is applied to the material, strain is what it does in response - I always used to get these the wrong way around.

> **E equals Fl/ea**

Young's Modulus = (force × length) / (extension × area)

Good luck with the others: I suggest imagining a hard man (grizzled veteran) who is actually secretly limp wristed and camp (he bends unlike hard materials), a tough guy (showy, probably with twin pistols) who literally goes to pieces in difficult situations (imagine his brittle bones snapping)  and a strong man (lifting a dumbbell) who is crushed to a pancake by the weight.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest learning about some of the formulas relating them - that way you're not just memorizing things but actually have some grasp of what goes into them. In particular, I only really know about stress and strain, and it's because I think of them as being the analogue in linear elasticity theory of "force" and "displacement" in Hooke's law.

Answer (score 0):

For **Shiny, Malleable, Ductile, Conductors** of heat and electricity and forming **Ionic** compounds, there is a mnemonic which goes like
**S**ilver
**M**ade
**D**esert i.e
**C**upcakes and
**I**ce-creams for after dinner