# Mnemonics for remembering physical data

Tags: terminology, mnemonic

Anyone have good mnemonics for remembering standard packets of data in physics?
Any field within physics would be welcomed.  Examples of such "packets":

- data in the standard model of particle physics
- charges/masses of common subatomic particles and light atoms
- cosmological data -- numbers, masses, luminosities
  (I recall "Oh Be A Fine Girl/Guy Kiss Me Right Now Smack" for star types)
- thermodynamics
- material properties
  (I note also [Mnemonics to remember various properties of materials](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75/mnemonics-to-remember-various-properties-of-materials))

Comment: Lots of, but in Polish (-;

Comment: @mbq: if you have something really good then leave it as a comment. I'd appreciate it. Although, perhaps chat would be better place for this.

Comment: Since it's a wiki, may we add an answer per language, and edit the relevant one ?

Comment: Anywayt, Wikipedia has a list in French http://fr.wikibooks.org/wiki/Liste_de_mn%C3%A9moniques#Physique

Comment: I invented this extra use of the familiar Roy G Biv: his initials are those of the light primaries, RGB, red green blue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

well everyone at least knows a mnemonic for the planets in the solar system.
"My Very Energetic Mother Just Served Us Nine Pizzas"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_mnemonic

also to remember where the minus sign goes in $\sigma_2$ of the Pauli Matrices I learned:

"the minus i rides high on the sigma y"

edit:

also found this list of some mnemonics

http://members.chello.nl/r.kuijt/index-physics.htm

Comment: I think this is the first time I see an outdated mnemonic :)

Comment: actually the wiki page lists an updated one: Many Very Educated Men Justify Stealing Unique Ninth ;)

Comment: I guess the 'unique ninth' being pluto? good except pluto isn't unique (part of the reason it was demoted). I still use My Very Excited Mother Jumped Straight Under Nine [Planets]

Comment: Thanks!  This plus the link is just what I was looking for.

Comment: +1 because I could never remember which Pauli matrix is which, but now I will.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one from my teacher back in High School:
Radiowaves, Microwaves, Infrared, Visible light, UV, X-rays, Gamma rays can be remembered as:

***Real Men Inevitably Visit Ugly eX-Girlfriends***